# Linear parameterization of nonlinear functions

Tags: real-analysis, nonlinear-analysis

Suppose $f(t,x(t)) \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $x(t) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ $(n \geq m)$ are continuous in their arguments and bounded, and that $f(t,0) = 0$.  Further, assume that the partial derivatives of $f$ are piecewise continuous and bounded (uniformly in $t$), and $\dot{x}(t)$ is bounded and piecewise continuous.

1) Can we say that there exists a parameterization such that $f(t,x(t)) = A(t) x(t)$ for all $t$ and $A(t)$ is continuous and bounded?

2) Can we argue that the $A(t)$ has bounded, piecewise continuous derivative?

3) What conditions are necessary for such a parameterization?

Regarding 1), $A(t) = f(t,x(t))x^\top(t)/\|x(t)\|^2$ comes to mind.  I believe its derivative would be piecewise continuous as well, but I seem to be having trouble putting everything together.

Comment: I guess the only requirement is that $f$ is linear in its second argument

Comment: Consider the scalar case with $f(t,x(t)) = x^2(t)$. Then $A(t) = x(t)$ is continuous, bounded, and has bounded and piecewise continuous derivative.  This would satisfy the conditions, but $f$ is not linear in $x$.  (I suppose I need to add that $\dot{x}$ is bounded, whoops)